# Get https certificate for GitLab server over tor/onion domain?

Tags: encryption, ssl, certificate, tor, gitlab

To host a GitLab server over Tor I would like to get an https certificate. Gitlab provides the opportunity to use a let's encrypt certificate. Let's encrypt requires a domain for registration, hence I tried to set:

```
external_url 'someoniondomain.onion'​
external_url 'http://someoniondomain.onion'​
external_url 'https://someoniondomain.onion'
```

Followed by:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl start
```

However, the first setting for the `external_url` returns:

> Running handlers: There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:
>
> GitLab external URL must include a schema and FQDN, e.g.
> http://gitlab.example.com/

The second and third setting for the `external_url` return:

Running handlers:

> There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:
>
> letsencrypt_certificate[<some_onion_domain>.onion]
> (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 5) had an error:
> Acme::Client::Error::RejectedIdentifier: acme_certificate[staging]
> (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb
> line 25) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::RejectedIdentifier: Error
> creating new order :: Cannot issue for "<some_onion_domain>.onion":
> The ACME server refuses to issue a certificate for this domain name,
> because it is forbidden by policy

Hence, I would like to ask, how could I get a https certificate for an onion domain?

[This post](https://github.com/letsencrypt/boulder/issues/4620#issuecomment-768230411) seems to refer to the possibility to serve https over `.onion` domains, hence I thought it might be possible to generate Letsencrypt certificates in a work-around.

Comment: It's possible, but apparently not through LetsEncrypt. You should try a different CA. DuckDuckGo's .onion site has a DigiCert certificate, so I would try DigiCert.

Comment: @DanielB Thank you, I adjusted my question in response to your comment to ask how to get an https certificate from any certificate provider (instead of Let's encrypt only)  for a `.onion` domain for GitLab.